# How to make similar navigation as Iphone 15 highlights slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

A newbie here. I'm new to StackOverflow, despite the fact that over the years I've found solutions here while googling different stuff. I have basic knowledge when it comes to html and css, but most of the times when I need to make something a bit out of the ordinary I usually search for similar solutions over the net. This time is not much different but the thing I really want to achieve is a bit (or more) complex for my understanding. I would really appreciate any tips & suggestions on how I can do it.

What I want to achieve is a design similar to the navigation of a media slider found on iphone 15 page here: https://www.apple.com/iphone-15-pro/ . If you look at the second section of that page you will see product highlights section with interesting navigation.

[iphone15 highlights navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8BKR.png)

Maybe doing something close to that navigation is an enourmous task, maybe it is not so monumental - still a newbie and can't tell. I would be happy to see your thoughts and suggestions. Thanks in advance!

The only kind of relevant thing I found, still not so close to the desired end result: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/robertraichle/pen/byZGZW)

```
HTML
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="background"></div>
    
    <div class="slider">

        <div class="slider__wrap swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="item swiper-slide"></div>

            <div class="item swiper-slide"></div>

            <div class="item swiper-slide"></div>

            <div class="item swiper-slide"></div>

            <div class="item swiper-slide"></div>

            <div class="item swiper-slide"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="slider__controls">

            <div class="slider__pagination"></div>

            <div class="slider__button-next"></div>
            <div class="slider__button-prev"></div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

```
CSS

html {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden!important;
}
a, a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
div {
    display: block;
}

.background {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: -owg-linear-gradient(150deg, #501edb 20%, #e22931);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(150deg, #501edb 20%, #e22931);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(150deg, #501edb 20%, #e22931);
    -pie-background: -pie-linear-gradient(150deg, #501edb 20%, #e22931);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(300deg, #501edb 20%, #e22931);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(300deg, #501edb 20%, #e22931);
    background: linear-gradient(150deg, #501edb 20%, #e22931);
}

.slider {
    z-index: 2;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 60px;
 
    .slider__wrap {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-align: start;
        -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
            -ms-flex-align: start;
                align-items: flex-start;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;

        & .swiper-slide {
            width: 300px;
            -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
                -ms-flex-negative: 0;
                    flex-shrink: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            height: 350px;
            background: #fff;
            -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
                    border-radius: 20px;
            pointer-events: none;
            -webkit-transition: all .3s;
            -o-transition: all .3s;
            transition: all .3s;
        }

        & .swiper-slide-active, .swiper-slide-prev, .swiper-slide-next {
            opacity: 1;
            pointer-events: auto;
        }

    }

    .slider__controls {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 12;
    
        & .slider__pagination {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 50px;

            & .swiper-pagination-bullet {
            width: 13px;
            height: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
            background: #fff;
            opacity: .2;
            margin: 0 5px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
                    border-radius: 20px;
            -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, background-color .5s, width .5s;
            -o-transition: opacity .5s, background-color .5s, width .5s;
            transition: opacity .5s, background-color .5s, width .5s;
            -webkit-transition-delay: .5s, .5s, 0s;
                 -o-transition-delay: .5s, .5s, 0s;
                    transition-delay: .5s, .5s, 0s;
            }        
        }
            
        & .swiper-pagination-clickable .swiper-pagination-bullet {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        & .slider__pagination .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
            opacity: 1;
            background: #ffffff;
            width: 100px;
            -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
                 -o-transition-delay: 0s;
                    transition-delay: 0s;
        }

        & .slider__button-next, .slider__button-prev {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            width: 27px;
            height: 44px;
            margin-top: -22px;
            z-index: 10;
            cursor: pointer;
            -webkit-background-size: 27px 44px;
                    background-size: 27px 44px;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        & .slider__button-prev {
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23007aff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
            left: 10px;
            right: auto;
        }

        & .slider__button-next {
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23007aff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
            right: 10px;
            left: auto;
        }

        & .slider__button-prev:focus, .slider__button-next:focus {
            outline: none!important;
        }

    }

}
```

```
JS

var swiper = new Swiper('.slider', {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    grabCursor: true,
    speed: 500,
    pagination: {
      el: '.slider__pagination',
      clickable: true,
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.slider__button-next',
      prevEl: '.slider__button-prev',
    },
});
```